# Core dump show only one stack frame

Tags: linux, debugging, crash, gdb, coredump

I have a crash and the application is compiled with symbols. When I run gdb I get only one stack frame.

The app uses shared libraries and some of the shared libraries are stripped.
Below is the output from GDB when I run `bt full`:

```
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x78461f68 in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0x24
```

Can anyone help me with how to proceed further in such cases? How do I get to know what call from my application ended at this address?

Comment: *`Cannot access memory at address 0x24`* is obviosuly wrong. Something is performing a wild read/write; you are in the third virtual function with a `NULL` `this` pointer in C++, etc... You need to provide more information, like your programming language and what is loaded at address 0x78461f68 .

Answer (score 0):

> How I get to know what call from my application ended at this address.

The most likely cause is stack overflow / stack corruption.

You should instrument your application with [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (available for recent versions of Clang and GCC) -- it is exceptionally good at pointing you straight at the problem.